# Updating navigation properties with the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am building an app to help host a wine night, where guests will try to identify more expensive bottles of wine.

To keep things simple, I'll elaborate on only two entites:

```
public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual Wine Wine { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string Guess { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WineAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the View where guests make a guess about which wine is the more expensive, I have hidden fields where I hold the unique identifiers for some of the other entities:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(event => event.Id)
```

Now, when a guest posts their choice via a Web API, the model is hydrated, but the model's navigation properties are anemic:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostChoice(Choice choice)
{
   /* At this point, the model looks like:
    Choice
       .Id = 0
       .Guess = "A",
       .Comment = "My comment!",
       .Event = { Event
                      .Id = 1,
                      .Name = ""
                      .Date = 01/01/0001 00:00:00
                }
}
```

So, if I attempt to perform an update on `Choice`, `Event` will also be updated, but with default values for its properties. Not good!

Before I save, I could do something like:

```
 choice.Event = db.Events.Single(e => e.Id == choice.Event.Id)
```

But there's one db hit to get all the necessary properties for `Event`, and then another one to needlessly update it with values that haven't changed. It seems like a ton of overhead.

Is there a simpler, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to update the `Event` entity? It looks like a simple `EventID` property on your `Choice` entity would suffice to set the one-to-many relationship between `Event` and `Choice`.

Comment: And perhaps I'm missing something simple. Would an EventID foreign key property on my Choice entity suffice? Would I declare both the foreign key property and the navigation property?

Comment: Yep, see my answer below. You will keep both the foreign key property and the navigation property. I wanted to be sure you were not wanting to do something else because it seems in this scenario the `ID` property was the only one being utilized from the `Event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `EventID` property to your `Choice` entity:

```
public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual Wine Wine { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string Guess { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to create the one-to-many relationship between `Event` and `Choice` and you will not need to save the `Event` navigation property when guests make a guess.

I'm not sure what you're model or view looks like, but with this approach you will simply assign the event ID from your `Event` entity to the `EventID` property. Then in the form you'll have a hidden input for the property:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventID)
```

Then simply update the `Choice` entity in the database without affecting the corresponding `Event`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while updating your model in db...

```
context.Entry(Choice).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(Choice).Property(x => x.Event).IsModified = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```